# How to extract description if meta tag does't exist?

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Many webpages doesn't have description meta tag, for example wikipedia. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_description_attribute) says, that If tag doesn't exist, then search engine, like Google get shorter paragraph. I don't know how to implement this behaviour using HtmlAgilityPack? If meta-tag empty or doesn't exist then get shorter paragraph from text. Below example work when description exist.

```
String description = (from x in content.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                      where x.Name.ToLower() == "meta"
                      && x.Attributes["name"] != null
                      && x.Attributes["name"].Value.ToLower() == "description"
                      select x.Attributes["content"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPATH, something like this, wrapped in a method:

```
    static string GetMetaDescription(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        // get a META element recursively in the document
        // which has a NAME attribute equal to 'description'
        // and a non empty CONTENT attribute.
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='description' and @content]");
        if (node == null)
            return null;

        // get the value of the CONTENT attribute
        return node.GetAttributeValue("content", null);
    }
```